# How to fetch target path from internet shortcut?

Tags: java

I have a different links in my page like,

`<a href="../test.url">Open</a>`

now when I click on this link, i get a *.url file in text mode.
I found that URL files has different formats as http://www.cyanwerks.com/file-format-url.html
show is there any easy way to fetch the target path from this text?

I know it is just simple string manipulation  but is there any easy way to parse it which can work for cross-platform URL shortcut files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see that URL file having same format as .ini file (key/value pair).
http://www.cyanwerks.com/file-format-url.html

If you are running your application in Desktop Application then, the files can be manipulated using basic file I\O or the ***GetPrivateProfileString, GetPrivateProfileSection, WritePrivateProfileSection, WritePrivateProfileSring*** API functions provided by Windows.

If you want to manually parse it and you having whole file content as one string only then i prefer you to follow below method:

```
private String getUrl(String fileContent) {
    fileContent = fileContent.trim();
    String[] contentList = fileContent.split("\r\n");
    for (String content : contentList) {
        if (content.toUpperCase().startsWith("URL")) {
            int i = content.indexOf("=");
            return content.substring(i + 1);
        }
    }
```

}